# Setting the starting value of an AUTO_INCREMENT field in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple question in creating table in database. Here's my code:

```
$query="CREATE TABLE users (
    userid int(5) not null AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    firstname varchar(20),
    lastname varchar(20),
    username varchar(30),
    password varchar(32),
    email varchar(50),
    age int(2),
    PRIMARY KEY (userid)
)";
```

I want the `USERID AUTO INCREMENT` to start in a `SPECIFIC NUMBER`.

example, starting in 99001....

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two ways to set the start value of an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field. You can either call the following `ALTER TABLE` command if your table already exists:

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 99001;
```

Otherwise you can also use the set the start value directly in the `CREATE TABLE` command as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   userid int(5) not null AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   firstname varchar(20),
   lastname varchar(20),
   username varchar(30),
   password varchar(32),
   email varchar(50),
   age int(2),
   PRIMARY KEY (userid)
) AUTO_INCREMENT = 99001;
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   userid int(5) not null AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   firstname varchar(20),
   lastname varchar(20),
   username varchar(30),
   password varchar(32),
   email varchar(50),
   age int(2),
   PRIMARY KEY (userid)
);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 99001;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, username, password) 
           VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM users;
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------+------+
| userid | firstname | lastname | username | password | email | age  |
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------+------+
|  99001 | a         | b        | c        | d        | NULL  | NULL |
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `AUTO_INCREMENT` keyword during table creation:

```
$query="CREATE TABLE users (
    userid int(5) not null AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    firstname varchar(20),
    lastname varchar(20),
    username varchar(30),
    password varchar(32),
    email varchar(50),
    age int(2),
    PRIMARY KEY (userid)
    ) AUTO_INCREMENT=99001";
```

**Edit**:

Corrected syntax.

Comment: I think the `AUTO_INCREMENT=99001` part needs to go after the last parenthesis, just like when setting the storage engine :)

Comment: Your syntax is a bit off. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html